# .ts included stream links gets stop after some time in exoplayer

Tags: video, streaming, codec, android, media

0

I have a link that streams. When I use the link for an IPTV player like Televizo, this plays for an unlimited of time, but when I use this link to my app Exoplayer or my computer's VLC player, this only gets played for some seconds.

The link - http://sample.com:8080/live/789/789/14756.ts

My Code -

```
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl);
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    player.prepare();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Cross-posted from Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77426525/2821954